# Query for finding duplicate records where 2nd field is different

Tags: sql

Probably very simple but given data of

TableA

```
FIELD1 | FIELD2
A      | 1
A      | 1
A      | 2
B      | 3
B      | 3
C      | 4
C      | 5
```

How can I find the duplicate of Field 1 where Field 2 is different.

e.g from data above I want to return records 3 (A2) and 6 (C5)

Thanks in advance

Comment: c4 is also different

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result as well.

Comment: which dbms (mysql, postgresql, tsql / sql-server, oracle) you are using?

Comment: Tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Which logic do you determine which is duplicated row? For e.g, if A2 is the main row, then A1 is the duplicated row, not A2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table_name t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT FIELD1, MIN(FIELD2) AS FIELD2
  FROM table_name 
  GROUP BY FIELD1
) t2 ON t1.FIELD1 = t2.FIELD1 AND t1.FIELD2 <> t2.FIELD2
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ce4ffe91faad0251254bd69c6f780bd)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where a.field2 > (select min(a2.field2)
                  from tableA a2
                  where a2.field1 = a.field1
                 );
```

You could also use window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             min(a.field2) over (partition by field1) as min_field2
      from tableA a
     ) a
where field2 > min_field2;
```